# IIS6&7 Inetpubfolder

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

There is a current debate between co-workers about the INETPUB folder. There are several people whom want  not to deploy web apps into the inetpub folder but create a virtual directory instead and have the apps live in a different folder. And, there are some that want to use the inetpub folder and not have to create the virtual directories.

I was wondering are there any pros or cons for not putting apps in the inetpub folder and just reference them through a virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason NOT to use the INETPUB folder, but that said, we don't use it.

However, the REASON we don't use it is because for purely technical reasons. Our back-end pre-processor (a proprietary ISAPI DLL) plays much nicer when you use a different directory.

The only other reason I can think of to not use it is "Security though Obscurity", if someone does gain access to the box they won't instantly know where to go to find the websites. Of course this will only slow them down by about 60 seconds, and security through obscurity is worse than no security.

Comment: It will also stop almost all of the dumb scripts which put data in INETPUB. It is also a good way to seperate data & (OS) code, putting the sites on a different drive.

Comment: Actually there's some very useful scripts under inetpub/adminscripts